# 18 Digit Julian Date / TimeStamp PHP Conversion?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a project for my work, it is using a lot of data from the mysql databases, alot of rows from the databases have a TimeStamp but they are 18 digits long.

I have a calculation that converts it into a friendly date in excel, DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS.

The calculation is as follows  (212262066420979000/86400000000) - 2415018.5  = value, and then format in excel into dd-mm-yy hh-mm-ss.

If I use php to do this calculation, I get the right value, but I can't set the format to look like a friendly date like you can in excel.

Is there any easy way of doing this in php?

Here is my code below

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM varmeas WHERE VARIABLE = 'WTSE';");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ROUTING_POS</th>
<th>VARIABLE</th>
<th>VAR_MEASURE_1</th>
<th>DATETIME_STAMP</th>
<th>FRIENDLY_DATE</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ROUTING_POS'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['VARIABLE'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['VAR_MEASURE_1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DATETIME_STAMP'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

This would output a table like -

```
ROUTING_POS VARIABLE    VAR_MEASURE_1          DATETIME_STAMP   
FLIS        WTSE            22.20             212262066888394000
```

Comment: `(212262066420979000 / 86400000000)-2415018.5`= `41718,3798724422`
What date does this represent?

Comment: How is the DATETIME_STAMP defined in the MySQL Schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(212262066420979000/86400000000) - 2415018.5 = value
```

Gives a value of `41718.379872442`, which is an MS Excel timestamp value for `20/03/2014  09:07:01`

To convert from an Excel timestamp to a Unix timestamp (based on the Windows 1900 calendar)

For a quick and dirty conversion from an Excel timestamp to a unix timestamp that can be used with PHP date functions:

```
$excelValue =  (212262066420979000/86400000000) - 2415018.5;
$unixValue = ($excelValue - 25569) * 86400;
```

Note that this will return a value in UST

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixValue);
```

or

```
$d = new DateTime('@' . (int)$unixValue, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**EDIT**

To integrate it with your existing code is as simple as adding:

```
$excelValue =  ($row['DATETIME_STAMP'] / 86400000000) - 2415018.5;
$unixValue = ($excelValue - 25569) * 86400;
$d = new DateTime('@' . (int)$unixValue, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo "<td>" . $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "</td>";
```

immediately after

```
echo "<td>" . $row['DATETIME_STAMP'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Hi, this worked perfectly, but I'm having trouble merging it with my code, by my code can you think of anyway I can make this bit -  echo "<td>" . $row['DATETIME_STAMP'] . "</td>"; - do that calculation that you gave me?   Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: - Hi Mark, is there any easy way to reverse the above formula of 04/02/2018 00:01:00 into a 18 digit timestamp, I've tried to reverse your answer but I don't get 212384462460000000 for that date above. Php gives me 4088745.464506 instead?  Sorry to bump an old post.

Comment: The logic to reverse the formula would be `$date = '04/02/2018 00:01:00';
$unixTimestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $date, new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$excelTimestamp = ($unixTimestamp->format('U') / 86400) + 25569;
$originalValue = ($excelTimestamp + 2415018.5) * 86400000000;
` but that will give you a float value, so you're probably better doing the last line using the [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension to give a string result

Comment: Just tried this formula echo bcadd($excelTimestamp, $add) * 864000000;   and got the following result - 2.1238446246E+172.123844192E+15 , can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `2.1238446246E+17` is `212384462460000000` expressed in scientific format, as PHP does when displaying numbers above a certain threshold.... you could use `sprint()` to express all the digits

Comment: But you should also do the multiply using bcmul() as well, not just the addition, otherwise the string result from the bcadd() will simply by converted back to a float by the multiplication: `echo bcmul(bcadd($excelTimestamp, $add), '864000000';`